# Add MP3 Files To Native Music Player?

Tags: music, mp3

I use Linux on the desktop and have zero access to iTunes. I'm in a position where I have to use an iPhone for a while.

I can plug my phone to my computer and mount the storage drive. Where would I dip my MP3 collection in order to pay them in the native application?

It's an iPhone 4S updated to the latest version of iOS.

Answer (score 1):

afaik since iOS 5 there is no longer a Linux Application that supports syncing Music to an iPhone (there used to be [GTKpod](http://www.gtkpod.org/wiki/Home))

The easiest would be to install [WINE](http://www.winehq.org) and then iTunes I suppose.

Comment: There's no place I can just drop my MP3 files on the phone, then let the music app scan? ...like every other phone?

Comment: No, the music app can't scan for files. It's made to be used in conjunction with iTunes